# HTTP request not returning desired json

Tags: java, json, http, httpclient

I am trying to send a http request to a website which is supposed to return a json response. The problem is that i am not getting the json data. But when i paste the url in a browser it displays the json output. Am a newbie. Kindly help.

Here is my code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url="http://directclientvendors.com/news24/api/get.php?type=news";
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response;
response = client.execute(request);
BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";

while(br.ready())
{
    line+=br.readLine();
}
System.out.println("line "+line);
```

Comment: What is the output as it is?

Comment: output : line . It doesnt even go into the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be executing a `GET` request and not a `POST`. Please change the request type to `HttpGet`. The browser executes a `GET` on the [URL](http://directclientvendors.com/news24/api/get.php?type=news) when you paste it on the address bar and hit enter.

Additionally use a Reader + StringBuilder / JsonReader / GSON to read from the URL's response content. String concatenation leads to the creation of additional objects unnecessarily.

[EDIT]

To my astonishment the API call works even when a `POST` call is made to get the resource. The problem must be in your parsing logic. Using a `JsonReader` works fine for me. This is just template code, but you can fill in the rest to get the other JSON elements. Regardless of whether `POST` works or not, you should still use `GET` for this call.

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://directclientvendors.com/news24/api/get.php?type=news");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8"));
        jsonReader.beginObject();
        if(jsonReader.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(jsonReader.nextName()); // prints 'news'
            // BEGIN_ARRAY etc to parse the rest
        }
        // END_OBJECT and cleanup
```